# Finding count of duplicate values and ordering in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with many columns, two of them are "movie title" and "age", I want to find the top 5 movies with the lowest average age of the people that rated them, but only include movies which have at least 100 ratings (so appear in at least 100 rows).

For example:

```
movie title      age

Title 1          10
Title 2          12
Title 2          12
Title 3          13
Title 3          13
Title 3          13
```

Should become:

```
movie title     # of ratings     avg age

Title 1         1                    10
Title 2         2                    12
Title 3         3                    13
```

It can be in the same or a new dataframe. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter creates a flag for each movie that is set to True if the movie title count is more than one hundred and False otherwise.

```
n = 100
filter = (df.groupby(['movie title'])['age']
          .transform(lambda group: group.count()) >= n)
```

Given the small size of your sample data, I will set `n` to be 2 and create my filter.

Now I just filter on movies with a count exceeding `n`, calculate the average age per group, and then take the five smallest (i.e. lowest age).

```
>>> df[filter.values].groupby('movie title').age.mean().nsmallest(5)
movie title
Title 2    12
Title 3    13
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

Comment: couldnt you use the  'filter' method after groupby directly?

Comment: This doesn't seem to filter out movies with less than 100 ratings when I run it?

Comment: It works if the dataframe only has the columns movie title and age.  See edit above for fix.

Answer (score 4):

Say you do

```
agg = df.age.groupby([df['movie title']]).agg({'ave_age': 'mean', 'size': 'size'})
```

You'll get a DataFrame with columns `ave_age` and `size`.

```
agg[agg['size'] > 100]
```

will give you only those that have more than 100 users. From there, sort by `agg.ave_age` and take the top 5. It should look something like this:

```
agg[agg['size'] > 100].sort_values(by='ave_age', ascending=True).head(5)
```

Comment: Have a look at the groupby.  I believe `df.title` throws an error and is not needed anyway.  Also, `size` is a dataframe property, so you may want to use a different variable name. `ascending=True` is the default parameter value so is not required, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit either.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander you're right - corrected. I believe that `pd.read_clipboard()` does strange stuff on this particular example. Consequently, I made some modifications, and apparently got one wrong.

Comment: I believe you want `agg = df.groupby('movie title').age.agg(...)`

Comment: Thanks, guys. @Alexander, unfortunately, I could only upvote your answer once.

Comment: I do like both solutions, so i wanted to compare how fast they are: Ami's - `100 loops, best of 3: 6.56 ms per loop`, Alexander's - `100 loops, best of 3: 16.9 ms per loop`

Comment: @MaxU Nice initiative. Also, thanks for your helpful comment before (even if you've since erased it).

Comment: @MaxU Yes, I am doing two `groupby` operations when I really should only be doing one. I believe Ami Tavory's answer is better.

Comment: @Alexander, that's a pity that you have removed your solution - it was useful for people learning pandas

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, you should really return it. It was a good answer. Thanks again for the help!